# Objective-C - Network services getting timeout error when app running on background for a long time

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, timeout, sendasynchronousrequest

I'm developing a little Objective-c app, and everything works fine, but when I run it on my iPhone and I let the app on background for a long time (all day for example) all network services get a timeout error, but if I close the app and start it again, it starts to work fine, what could be the problem?

PD. I'm using `NSURLConnection` `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:compltionHandler:` and `NSURLConnection` `initWhitRequest:delegate:`